# NSTimer invalidate not work

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I can not stop the timer `NSTimer` created to perform secondary operations.

I have read and tried all sorts of possible Web guides but none have worked and the timer continues to run even when the Controller is destroyed. Below is the code in question:

```
/* Copy banner in a temp array and change order to random value */
private func getBanners(){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let banners = self.synchronizer.getAllBanners()?.sorted("ordine")
    if let banners = banners {
        for banner in banners {
            let random = Double.random(0.0, 1.0)
            let currentOrderValue = banner.ordine
            self.banners.append(banner)
            do {
                try realm.write({
                    self.banners.last!.ordine = currentOrderValue + random
                })
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

}

/*Update index of banner to show */
func updateIndex(timer : NSTimer) {
    if self.index+1 < self.banners.count {
        for banner in self.banners{
            print(banner.name + " \(banner.ordine)")
        }
        self.index+=1
    } else {
        self.index = 0
    }
    self.setImageBanner()
}

/* Set image of banner to show*/
private func setImageBanner() {
    if self.banners.count > 0 {
        self.bannerImage.hidden = false
        let banner = self.banners[self.index]
        let file = banner.images[0]
        self.synchronizer.loadImageURL(file.link, imageView: self.bannerImage)
    } else {
        self.bannerImage.hidden = true
    }
}

/* Start Timer */
func startTimerForBanners() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.getBanners()
    })
    self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateIndex(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer!, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}

/* Open link on banner click */
func openLink(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if self.index >= 0 && self.index < self.banners.count {
        let banner = self.banners[self.index]
        print(banner.name)
        self.synchronizer.openLink(banner.url)
    }
}

func trialLesson(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer){
    performSegueWithIdentifier("trial_lesson_segue", sender: nil)

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if let timer = self.timer {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: From where you are calling `startTimerForBanners` ?

Comment: did you try timer=nil?

Comment: @kocakmstf `timer = nil` does not stop the timer.

Comment: @kocakmstf yes but timer = nil not work...

Comment: @MidhunMP I calling startTimeForBanner from **viewDidLoad()** method...

Answer (score 0):

you need to invalidate the timer before starting a new timer. Currently I believe you are calling "startTimerForBanners" many times may be, so many timer thread has been initiated. One approach is to invlidate all timer one by one or just invalidate before starting new one like this

```
/* Start Timer */
func startTimerForBanners() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.getBanners()
    })
**self.timer.invalidate()**
    self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateIndex(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer!, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}
```

Comment: The `timer` is optional, so you'd do `timer?.invalidate()`.

Comment: Yes the timer is an optional type. I invalidate the timer before destroy the controller but it not work...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your controller is really deallocated? 
There is one thing you should be always aware about `NSTimer`: it retains it's target.

I would suggest to:

1. Start your timer in `viewWillAppear`
2. Invalidate and set timer to nil in `viewDidDisappear`
3. Also try replacing your start timer code with this (Swift 3):

`timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateIndex(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`